# Java Threading Tutorial

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm looking through the Java concurrency tutorials to get an idea of how this works in Java and had a question regarding the "MsLunch" example @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

I'm trying to understand in the MsLunch example, the difference between coding it as shown, and using 2 synchronized methods.

From what I can understand, using the `synchronized` keyword on methods relies on an instrinic lock associated with that methods object. So if a `class` has two `synchronized` methods `a()` and `b()`,  `a()` and `b()` cannot be called concurrently on the same object.

But coding `a()` and `b()` as shown in the MsLunch class allows both methods to be called on the same object at the same time.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't see `a()` and `b()` in the link you shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MsLunch` example uses `synchronized` blocks with different object instances to lock. Hence both `inc1()` and `inc2()` can run concurrently.

If it were synchronized methods, in that case `this` will be used to lock, methods `inc1()` and `inc2()` would be executed serially.

Answer (score 0):

In http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html
MSLunch is having Sync block rather than sync methods that too on two different locks so Yes Two threads will not be mutually blocked and will be able to access methods at the same time.